# Flutter - Create a cURL request using the package curl/curl.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a cURL web request using the [curl/curl.dart package](https://pub.dev/packages/curl). However, I get the error `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.`. How do I convert `String` to `Uri`?

Here is my complete code:

```
final request = new Request("POST", "http://my.web.url/webservice/rest/server.php");

final wstoken = "my_token";
final moodlewsrestformat = "json";
final wsfunction = "core_user_create_users";
final username = "test_user_3";
final firstname = "John";
final lastname = "Doe";
final email = "jogn.doe@gmail.com";
final password = "password_for_john";

request.bodyFields = {
  "wstoken" : wstoken,
  "moodlewsrestformat": moodlewsrestformat,
  "wsfunction": wsfunction,
  "users[0][username]" : username,
  "users[0][firstname]" : firstname,
  "users[0][lastname]" : lastname,
  "users[0][email]" : email,
  "users[0][password]" : password
};

print(toCurl(request));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html), I saw that you could probably use the `Uri.tryParse(urlString)` method.

```dart
final request = new Request("POST", Uri.tryParse("http://my.web.url/webservice/rest/server.php"));

final wstoken = "my_token";
final moodlewsrestformat = "json";
final wsfunction = "core_user_create_users";
final username = "test_user_3";
final firstname = "John";
final lastname = "Doe";
final email = "jogn.doe@gmail.com";
final password = "password_for_john";

request.bodyFields = {
  "wstoken" : wstoken,
  "moodlewsrestformat": moodlewsrestformat,
  "wsfunction": wsfunction,
  "users[0][username]" : username,
  "users[0][firstname]" : firstname,
  "users[0][lastname]" : lastname,
  "users[0][email]" : email,
  "users[0][password]" : password
};

print(toCurl(request));
```